# Toucher au / le chômage

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

> Grâce à mon ancienneté, j’ai le droit de toucher **au** chômage.

Je vois que l'expression "toucher **au** chômage" est répandue surtout au Québec. Les Français écrivent "toucher **le** chomage". Est-ce que "toucher **au** chômage" est considéré comme fautif en France ?

Comment: On dit souvent ça mais je le trouve un peu expressif pour l'écrit et la réduction sans toucher etc. _j'ai droit au chômage_ est plus usuelle pour moi quand on parle. Techniquement au Canada il s'agit de _prestations d'assurance-chômage_ dont une personne est _bénéficiaire_.

Comment: [Touchez pas au grisbi](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0046451/)

Answer (score 5):

Pas une faute, par contre je (France métropolitaine) n'emploierais 'toucher au chômage' que pour signifier 'changer ses modalités' (sujet=gouvernement par exemple), donc un sens bien différent.

Comme commenté par @jlliagre, 'au' pourrait aussi être utilisé dans "Je me demande combien je vais toucher au chômage" qui est équivalent à "Je me demande combien je vais toucher quand je serai au chômage".